# Prove that L is a sub-language of the CFG G by using induction. (CFG,Induction,School)

Tags: logic, proof-writing, induction, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

i am asking for help with a question from a course in Logic im reading at university. I am aware that this type of question is frequently asked here(i have looked at alot of other questions/answers) but i think it would be very helpful if i had some tips specific for my problem.

The question is:

> Consider the following grammar: S → SS | aSb | ϵ
>
> Prove that the following language is one of its sub-languages. Use induction.
> $${a^nb^n | n ≥ 0}$$

Im very new to induction and cannot figure out where to begin. Ofcourse you can immediately see that as long as you select the production "aSb", any amount of times, then end with an epsilon, you will indeed get $a^nb^n$. But if you select the production "SS" you will no longer get that language.

So i want to know how to deal with that it asks for a sub-language instead of the full language, and also i would like to know how to use induction make this proof.

I realize that i am pretty much asking for the entire answer here but if you can give me some help without giving away the full answer that would be very helpful.

Thanks

Edit: Thank you for all the help so far. If i use it i come up with something like:

Induction over n: Proving that n=1 generates string "ab".

Do i prove this by this line: $S->aSb->aϵb->ab$

Or by this: $a^1b^1 = ab$ ?

Moving on; Inductive assumption: This holds for n=k.

$a^kb^k$

Now, prove that this holds for k+1.

$a^{k+1}b^{k+1} = a^ka^1b^kb^1$

I now ask for feedback on my attempt. Thanks again.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. The question does not ask that $\{a^nb^n\}$ is the language of this grammar but a *sublanguage*. This means that all words $a^n b^n$ are in the language, not that there are no others.

Comment: @CaptainLama Ok thank you for confirming that. So to prove this with induction, can i(just guessing here) make a case for 0 productions
(0 a's and 0 b's), then 1 production (1a1b) etc? I just dont see how to prove this.. any further help is appreciated.

Comment: For induction prove that $ab$ for $n=1$ is generated by this language and then assume it true for  $n=k$ then prove it for $n=k+1$ .....these are the basic induction steps

Comment: I edited my answer. Any further help from you guys is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with this topic but with your understanding of logic and induction. First let me point out what's wrong with your attempt.

**Errors**

Let $G$ be the given CFG.

> n=1 generates string "ab"

This is unfortunately meaningless. What does "generate" mean? How can "$n=1$" do anything? If you want to say "$a^1 b^1$ is generated by $G$", say so. Don't say anything else.

> S−>aSb−>aϵb−>ab

This line is true for $G$. You could say "$a^1 b^1$ is generated by $G$, via S−>aSb−>aϵb−>ab".

> Inductive assumption: This holds for $n=k$.
>
> $a^k b^k$.

$a^k b^k$ is just a string, **not a sentence**! Just like you can't say "This holds for $n = k$: Elephant!", so also what you wrote is simply meaningless and has no truth value.

> Now, prove that this holds for $k+1$.

Not sure what you're talking about here. Are you referring to proving the following line?

> $a^{k+1} b^{k+1} = a^k a^1 b^k b^1$.

If so, then this has nothing to do with induction, because this very line is always true regardless of $k$.

**Correct structure**

Now here is the correct proof structure.

> Let $G$ be the given CFG.
>
> Let $P(n)$ be equivalent to "$G$ generates $a^n b^n$", for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> $G$ generates $a^0 b^0$ via $S \to ε = a^0 b^0$.
>
> Thus $P(0)$ is true.
>
> For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $P(n)$ is true:
>
> $G$ generates $a^n b^n$.
>
> Thus $S \to^* a^n b^n$.
>
> $G$ generates $a^{n+1} b^{n+1}$ via $S \to \cdots \to a^{n+1} b^{n+1}$.
>
> Thus $P(n+1)$ is true.
>
> Therefore by induction $P(n)$ is true for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> Therefore $G$ generates $a^n b^n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Your task is now to fill in the blanks where I put "$\cdots$". You have to figure out how to use the previous line in order to get from starting symbol $S$ to $a^{n+1} b^{n+1}$. This should be easy. Write your solution in a comment and I'll check it.

Comment: Hello. Thank you so much for the answer, this is exactly the kind of help i need(As you noted, i have no understanding of induction, this is pretty much my first induction proof.)

I am embarrased to tell you i still cannot figure out how to fill the blanks as you asked me to. I mean it is obvious that you just have to get the production "aSb" one more time than for P(n) but i dont know how to write that.

Question; when you say G generates a^n b^n, is this what you call inductive assumption? Because this is what we were supposed to proove.

Thanks again

Comment: @Ldvg: I hate to use the high-school terminology because it is ridiculously taught, and usually I've to **undo** all the wrong teaching that my students have from before. We always have to construct a predicate $P$ such that we want to prove every natural number satisfies. Then we prove that $0$ satisfies $P$. Then we prove that given any natural number $n$ that satisfies $P$, we can show that $n+1$ also satisfies $P$. Once we proven these, we can conclude that every natural number satisfies $P$, simply because we consider natural numbers to be exactly those obtainable from $0$ by adding $1$.

Comment: @Ldvg: To fill in the blank, you are right that you need one more time, so just do that. Now you hope you can prove $S \to aSb \to \cdots \to a^{n+1} b^{n+1}$. Can you fill in the blank now using the previous line?

Comment: I guess i would write something like $S -> aSb -> aa^nb^nb -> a^{n+1}b^{n+1}$

Comment: @Ldvg: Right, but you should say $aSb \to^* a a^n b^n b$ to denote that some arbitrary number of steps were used, not necessarily exactly one. And the last part should be an equality $a a^n b^n b = a^{n+1} b^{n+1}$, not a CFG derivation step. Do you see how it works? The first step was the extra step you said, the second sequence comes from the previous line (which was guaranteed by $P(n)$ being true), and the last is an equality of strings.

Comment: Oh right. That makes sense. That is all then for the full proof? Thanks alot for your help :)

Comment: @Ldvg: Indeed. The structure of a normal induction proof is always like this, and for this question only that one line was the part you actually need to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

1. Given languages $L, L'$, we say $L'$ is a **sublanguage** of $L$ if $L' \subseteq L$. That is, if all words of $L'$ are also words of $L$.
2. For the language $\{a^nb^n\mid n\ge0\}$, the obvious variable to induct over is $n$. We can use induction to prove that $a^nb^n$ is in the given CFG for all $n$.

---

In general, it is often beneficial to prove things about languages using **structural induction**: the principle that if the results of all rules of formation of the language fulfil a certain condition if all inputs do.

For example, taking $S \to SS\mid aSb\mid \epsilon$, we can prove using structural induction the statement: an expression resulting from these rules contains no other symbols but the metasymbol $S$ and $a,b$.

The proof then proceeds by checking that starting with $S$ (for which the premise holds true), the rules of formation preserve the truth of this statement.